# http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v is empty

Tags: python, docker, localhost

I'm really excited to start working with the package mordecai. I've been trying to run mordecai on my computer (Windows), using the steps described here: https://github.com/ryerson-ggl/mordecai-geoparser-on-windows. I've tried all steps mentioned earlier in the forum, but I'm not managing to successfully fulfill the last step. I have the geonames_index container running on Docker, but my http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v lists nothing (even after few minutes). Logs of docker give that:

docker message:

```
[2021-01-27T15:56:01,387][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [oP84io9] [gc][1710] overhead, spent [476ms] collecting in the last [1s]  
[2021-01-27T16:21:39,429][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] stopping ...  
[2021-01-27T16:21:39,467][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] stopped  
[2021-01-27T16:21:39,467][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] closing ...  
[2021-01-27T16:21:39,481][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] closed  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,805][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [] initializing ...  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,918][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [oP84io9] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (C:)]], net usable_space [234.6gb], net total_space [475.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [9p]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,918][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [oP84io9] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,926][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] node name [oP84io9] derived from node ID [oP84io93T0CFAVLVvVYI-g]; set [node.name] to override  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,926][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] version[5.5.2], pid[1], build[b2f0c09/2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z], OS[Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_141/25.141-b15]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:49,927][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,737][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [ingest-common]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [lang-expression]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [lang-groovy]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [lang-mustache]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [lang-painless]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [parent-join]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [percolator]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [reindex]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,738][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [transport-netty3]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,739][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] loaded module [transport-netty4]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:50,739][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [oP84io9] no plugins loaded  
[2021-01-27T16:26:52,364][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule ] [oP84io9] using discovery type [zen]  
[2021-01-27T16:26:53,069][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] initialized  
[2021-01-27T16:26:53,069][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] starting ...  
[2021-01-27T16:26:53,255][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService ] [oP84io9] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}  
[2021-01-27T16:26:53,267][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks ] [oP84io9] max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2021-01-27T16:26:56,315][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService ] [oP84io9] new_master {oP84io9}{oP84io93T0CFAVLVvVYI-g}{tM6d7PW1TRuig-bo3RjjyQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)  
[2021-01-27T16:26:56,336][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [oP84io9] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}  
[2021-01-27T16:26:56,336][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [oP84io9] started  
[2021-01-27T16:26:56,395][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService ] [oP84io9] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

I did notice the "max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]" line but I've unfortunetly no clue how to fix this..

Any clues on how to fix this, and http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v with the data listed in it?
Much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out entering the following commands in the command prompt did the trick:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```